# Getting 503 error when using JSoup to read an element from a webpage

Tags: java, http, jsoup

So I've been using the following code to find a specific element on a page given the specific id in the method. However, it seems that the website returns a 403 when I don't define a user-agent, and I get a 503 error when I do use a user-agent.
The website seems to use cloudflare, which from what I've heard is used to prevent DDOS attacks - so I'm a little confused as to why I'm not being able to read the page?

```
public static String getMargin(final int id) {
        String url = "https://rsbuddy.com/exchange?id=" + id + "&";
        Document document = null;
        try {
            document = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(30000)
                    .userAgent(
                            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36")
                    .get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return document.select("#buy-price").text();

    }
```

How would I be able to have it so that I can finally read the element from the webpage instead of receiving a 403 forbidden or 503 unavailable error? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect with `ignoreHttpErrors` set

```
Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(30000)
    .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
    ...
```

The page content will be what you see when you connect using your browser. This page contains a small script (looks like it's generated on each request). The script will calculate a value which it sets into the `jschl-answer` field of the following form before submitting it

```
<form id="challenge-form" action="/cdn-cgi/l/chk_jschl" method="get"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="jschl_vc" value="some-generated-value"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="pass" value="some-generated-value"> 
    <input type="hidden" id="jschl-answer" name="jschl_answer"> 
</form>
```

The form has to be submitted using the correct values (also, don't forget to get/set cookies).

So the key point will be to calculate the `jschl-answer` by either finding their algorithm (that's gonna be tough) or by reading the `script` tag, modifying it to be able to run locally and executing it locally.

All in all it's not gonna be an easy task, but I think it's doable.

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup isn't the best tool here. There's a challenge to solve before accessing the actual page. I'd suggest you to use one of the tools below:

- [ui4j](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwighJHl7YjMAhVJWxoKHQfkBTgQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fui4j%2Fui4j&usg=AFQjCNEhutAM87YahDqVUbqWGJJNjifKLw&sig2=IhWLT5npp5Ja59SSM3vEhg)
- [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)

You'll have less headaches...